# Cant get UISwitch constraints to work - swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint, uiswitch

I'm trying to create a UISwitch programmatically but for some reason I can't get any constraints to work. If I don't use any constraints the UISwitch is created but in the top left corner.

I tried creating the UISwitch by adding in the constraints when declaring my switch and this does move the switch to a different place. However this is a problem as I want to it to be constrained against other items in my view.

```
class cameraController: UIViewController {

    var switchOnOff: UISwitch {
        let switchOnOff = UISwitch()
        switchOnOff.isOn = false
        switchOnOff.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        switchOnOff.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchButton(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        return switchOnOff
    }
}    

extension cameraController{
    @objc func switchButton(_ sender:UISwitch){
        if (sender.isOn == true){
            print("UISwitch state is now ON")
        }
        else{
            print("UISwitch state is now Off")
        }
    }
}

extension cameraController {
    private func setupLayouts() {

        view.addSubview(switchOnOff)

        switchOnOff.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
        switchOnOff.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: photosButtonIcon.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true

    }
}
```

I want to be able to add my constraints for the switch into my setupLayouts extension and not when the switch is being declared.

The error I am getting when running the above code is:

> **Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)**

I am getting this error on the first line of the constraints in my setupLayouts extension.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Put a print statement inside of your `switchOnOff` property code and see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a lazy var to have `self` inside this block which is a closure , your current code is a computed property which returns a switch for every reference and that causes a crash in constraints as the switch added to view is not the same object as the one you set constraints for

```
lazy var switchOnOff: UISwitch = {
    let switchOnOff = UISwitch()
    switchOnOff.isOn = false
    switchOnOff.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    switchOnOff.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchButton(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    return switchOnOff
}()
```

Then call `setupLayouts` inside `viewDidLoad` , btw extension is totally irrelevant to this problem

Comment: When I try an make the variable lazy I get this error **'lazy' must not be used on a computed property** which takes it back to it being just var.

Comment: copy all code in answer as it's , above not only `lazy` is added

Comment: Sorry my bad, that all works now thank you! Although I actually cant see the difference apart from **lazy** being added. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @spoax The `()` after the closing `}`.